# Change image every 7 days, then repeat when at last image

Tags: php

I am trying to display a piece of content (image for now) that lasts 7 days, then changes to the next piece of content.

There are 6 piece of content I need to cycle through.. after the 7th day on content item #6. I need to start over at content item #1.

The general approach I am taking is, get a UNIX timestamp, and divide by 7 day, and modulus by the total content items.

I saw this as a suggestion but not clear what the `$timestamp` is referring to?

```
$weeknumber = $ceil((time() – $starttimestamp) / 604800);

if ($weeknumber > {totalimages}) {
                $ weeknumber = $weeknumber % {totalimages};
}
```

This `(time() - $timestamp)` doesn't make sense to me

I'm expecting a return of 1-6  (or 0-5) and then do/load whatever based on that return value. I feel like I'm missing a part of it.

```
$unixStamp = time();
echo date('r', $unixStamp) . "<br />"; //outputs correct/current date

$weekCount1 = (floor($unixStamp / (60000*60*24*7) % 6) + 1);
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 1: ".$weekCount1;
echo '<br>';

$weekCount2 = (floor($unixStamp / 604800) % 6);
$weekCount2a = ($unixStamp / 604800) % 6;
$weekCount2b = (floor(time() - $unixStamp / 604800));
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 2: ".$weekCount2 .'<br>';
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 2: ".$weekCount2a .'<br>';
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 2: ".$weekCount2b .'<br>';
```

That being said, I'm also not clear on how I can TEST to ensure it will change/update correctly?  (Do I temporarily add some days/weeks to the $unixStamp to force a different date?)

Another attempt and trying to get different values:

```
$unixStamp = time();
echo date('r', $unixStamp) . "<br /><br />"; //outputs correct/current date
$startDate = strtotime('2015-03-01 00:00:00');


$weekCount1 = (floor($unixStamp / (60000*60*24*7) % 6) + 1);
$weekCount2a = (floor($startDate - $unixStamp / 604800) % 6) + 1;
//$weekCount2a = (floor($startDate - $unixStamp / 604800) % 6);
$weekCount2b = ($unixStamp / 604800) % 6;
$weekCount2c = (floor(time() - $unixStamp / 604800));
$weekCount2d = (ceil($unixStamp / 604800) % 6);
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 1: ".$weekCount1 .'<br>';
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 2a: ".$weekCount2a .'<br>';
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 2b: ".$weekCount2b .'<br>';
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 2c: ".$weekCount2c .'<br>';
echo "ARTICLE TO GRAB 2d: ".$weekCount2d .'<br>';
```

I had added and changed a start date to subtract form the unixStamp, in order to get a time difference form when the rotqation is to start vs the unixStamp and trying to get a return for that. However, it never changes regardless of the start date?

Latest attempt: seems to update when I refresh though, instead of going off the startDate:

```
  $unixStamp = time();
    $startDate = strtotime('2015-02-1 00:00:00'); 
    $weekCount = ceil($unixStamp - $startDate  / 604800);
    echo "CONTENT ID TO GRAB: ".$weekCount .'<br>';

    if ($weekCount > 6) {
         $weekCount = $weekCount % 6;
         echo "CONTENT TO GRAB: ".$weekCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the week number of the year, with your modulus:

```
$dayId = date('W') % 7;
```

The number returned by `date()` will start at 0 and increment to the end of the year every week. Thus this will give a reliable 0...6 cycle without much code.

Comment: wouldnt that change every day?  (havent tested it)..  I also dont see anything with a 'start date' to have it begin @ 0?

Comment: Ah, I misread the question @whispers - OK, now using week number. I don't understand your comment about a start date - do you need one? If the synchronisation of the cycle needs to be shifted, you can add a constant to the date function before taking a modulus. The `date()` function will use the current date/time, which I assume is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code: (seems to be working fine now)

```
  $unixStamp = time();
  $startDate = strtotime('2015-03-27 00:00:00'); 
  $weekCount = ceil(($unixStamp - $startDate)  / 604800) - 1;
  if ($weekCount > 6) {
      $weekCount = $weekCount % 6;
  }
```

Comment: `echo date('W',  strtotime('2015-03-27 00:00:00')) % $amount_of_images;`. Also it does not make any sense to check wether the value is larger than the amount of images and then do a mod division

Comment: @DarkBee - tested your code.. (just needed to add the -1 to start at 0).. if you make this an answer.. I'll accept, its must more cleaner/smaller code than my approach!  thanks!


   `echo date('W', strtotime('2015-03-28 00:00:00')) % $amount_of_images - 1 .'<br>';`

Comment: update: actually DarkBee- your code does -not- work.

If I used today as the start date to get content (which should return a zero for the first 7 days from start date).. you get a '2':

`$totalArticles = 6;
echo date('W', strtotime('2015-03-30 00:00:00')) % $totalArticles;`

Comment: (You need to use the 'at' sign to notify people, whispers e.g. @DarkBee).

Comment: didnt realize I didnt.. (I usually do)  :)